# mod_rewrite messing up header queries

Tags: php, mysql, mod-rewrite, pdo, duplicates

I have a lot of mod_rewrites in a local .htaccess file which basically follow this template:

```
RewriteRule ^page\/?$ /page.php [L,QSA]
```

Each of these pages has a header.php include that contains a single SQL insert:

```
$new_visit = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO stats (ip_address, clientdata, page_title, timestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, UTC_TIMESTAMP())");
$new_visit->execute(array($ip, $clientdata, $page_title));
```

The problem is that every time a page is visited, $new_visit is called three times instead of one: once for the actual page in question, and two duplicates (which interestingly use "index.php" for $page_title no matter what the redirected page was).

If anyone could help me fix this while leaving both mod_rewrite and some semblance of my visitors system intact, I'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a lot of mod_rewrites in a local .htaccess file

^ that's your problem.

I ran into a similar case where I simply wasn't sure what was happening. Turns out that an image didn't exist so the system couldn't generate a link to it, so instead it generated a link to index.php (or something similar). The browser then fetched that script as if it were expecting an image. This explained my 'ghost' request.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the guidance. How did you solve it? Did you fix the offending images/404s or did you change the mod_rewrites?

Comment: Can't thank you enough, managed to isolate something that (perhaps stupidly on my part) I'd never have managed to get on my own. Thanks again.